# Output from radio feeding both a speaker and microphone input

Tags: audio

I am trying to connect the output from a radio both to a speaker and taking the same signal and inputting it to the microphone input on a computer. The radio has no internal speaker, just a jack to feed an external speaker. The problem I am having is that the external speaker (required) is acting as a microphone and any noise near the speaker is also being fed into the computer. I need to isolate the speaker from the mic input. Also, the signal needs to be attenuated because of the strength. Any help would be appreciated, as everything I have tried, has not worked.

Bob

Comment: That is a bit surprising, but if it is actually the case, you would need to use an amplifier between the shared signal and the speaker in order to buffer the signal and prevent such return influence.

Comment: yeah, loudspeakers and microphones as transducers have a lot in common, but loudspeakers make awful microphones.

Answer (score 1):

something like this will give quite a lot of isolation, but it's not perfect.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo9XOS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

else go with Chris's suggestion an add another amplifier before the speaker.

Comment: What is the purpose of R2? And why its value?

Comment: it absorbs most of the sound entering through the speaker, chosen to make the system impedance seen by the radio close to 8 ohms.